# Order of operations in Django Templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm trying to call a dictionary named test with a key 'example' corresponding to a value 'OK'. I am trying to call it inside of a Django template, i.e. `{{test.example}}`. The problem is that I want to call this dynamically, so I pass an object and it has an ID of 'example' -> `{{test.(object.id)}}`. How do I go about this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `{{test.example}}` is not how you get the key example from the dictionary (?). Maybe you should explain the use case of this and a more elegant solution can be described

Comment: Basically just get the object.id first, and then get a value corresponding to the key in the test dictionary. `test.example` was just a quick example (and it works, somewhat).